# convert numerically indexed associative-array in PHP, to valid JavaScript Object via JSON

Tags: php, json, redbean

Let's say you have a numerically indexed array that looks like this (obtained via `RedBeanPHP's` `find` operation):

```
[
[33=>["name"=>"John", "age"=25]], 
[55=>["name"="Jane", "age"=23]]
]
```

where 33 and 55 are `id's` of each of the 2 "beans" (basically associative-arrays).

And you want to convert the array to JSON so you can send it to a JavaScript client and use the data there as a JavaScript Object.

But you can't simply `JSON_encode` this because you'll end up with numerical keys in a JavaScript Object, and JavaScript doesn't like that.

What strategy can you use to convert this array to a JavaScript Object via JSON so that all the data (including `id` of each bean) is available at the JavaScript end? (To the `RedBeanPHP` folks out there: I'm hoping there's a native `RedBeanPHP` way to do this that I haven't found yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. You should try this. First iterate through the outer array and inside that get the key i.e `id` of the data. Add `id` to other values and push that array into resultant one.

```
$result = array();
$arr = [[33=>["name"=>"John", "age"=>25]],[55=>["name"=>"Jane", "age"=>23]]];
foreach ($arr as $ar) {
    foreach ($ar as $key => $value) {
        $value['id'] = $key;
        array_push($result, $value);
    }
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Output :-

```
[{"name":"John","age":25,"id":33},{"name":"Jane","age":23,"id":55}]
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is using `array_map` to loop thru the array. Use `array_values` to get all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

```
$arr = [
    [33=>["name"=>"John", "age"=>25]], 
    [55=>["name"=>"Jane", "age"=>23]]
];

$result = array_map(function($o){
    return array_values($o)[0];
}, $arr);

echo json_encode( $result );
```

This will result as:

```
[{"name":"John","age":25},{"name":"Jane","age":23}]
```

Answer (score 2):

For your associative array:

```
    $array = array(33 => array("name" => "John", "age" => 25), 55 => array("name" => "Jane", "age" => 23));
```

PHP json_encode function:

```
$good_json  = json_encode($array,  JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Produces JSON for JavaScript object (string "name" : value pair):

```
{"33":{"name":"John","age":25},"55":{"name":"Jane","age":23}}
```